# Add data to a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building my first react component and am trying to add items to the parent component via an external click event. The user basically chooses from a list of search results and I want these to go into the react component. The problem is, it seems to create a new component every time?

```
var MatchApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div id="tasks">Here</div>
    );
   }
});

var MatchList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <a id={this.props.match}>Matching element</a>
    );
  }
});

document.getElementById("hits-container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if( e.target.classList.contains('matching_link') ) {
    //get matching ID reference
    var $match = e.target.id.replace( /^\D+/g, '');

    //now send to react
    ReactDOM.render(<MatchList match={$match}/>, document.getElementById('tasks'));
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<MatchApp/>, document.getElementById('example'));
```

What I am trying to achieve.

//search results loaded dynamically.

```
<div id="hits-container">
<div class="hit">
<!-- User clicks link below to send to matching container ( MatchApp ) -->
    <a href="#" id="6574" class="matching_link"></a>
</div>
```

//matching container where I want to build an element containing the "hits" from the search results that the user has clicked on above.

```
<div id="example">
<div id="tasks">

<!-- Loaded from the above hit hopefully into the react component -->
<a href="http://somewhere.com" id="match_6574">Matching element</a>

</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to go through the react [tutorials](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/use-react-with-other-libraries.html) on  interfacing react's life cycle methods with outside libraries such as jQuery

Comment: You're telling it to render a new one every time. `ReactDOM.render(<MatchList match={$match}/>, document.getElementById('tasks'))` Will replace the contends of `tasks` with a new `MatchList`. What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: Basically I want to get an ID from what the user clicks ( search results are SaaS ) then send that to my react component which will then get details from the database about the users choice.

Comment: I meant with the rendering. You said the problem was that it "creates a new component every time." Ok, why is that wrong? Your code calls `ReactDOM.render` in the click handler... creating a new component every time. If that isn't what you want, you don't explain what you *do* want. Your code does not contain the problem you are experiencing, and your description involves code that nobody can see. I don't think its possible to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Tyrsius and apologies for being so vague. I've updated the question to hopefully show what I am trying to do with React. Thanks again.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. Here is [a codepen](http://codepen.io/tyrsius/pen/MKgGwE?editors=101)

Comment: @Tyrsius would you be able to advise how I would be able to persist several "test links" into the component?

Comment: I've added an answer that does this. I highly recommend you go through the React tutorials, as they cover this. Its pretty basic stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to ***add*** items to you list, you have to keep track of them somewhere. A basic example might look like this ([codepen](http://codepen.io/tyrsius/pen/MKgGwE?editors=001))

Take note of how the `MatchApp` takes a list, and `map`s that list into a `<ul>`. The jQuery handler simply pushes each match into an array, and gives the array to the app so it can update the list.

```
var MatchApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var matches = this.props.matches.map(function(match) {
      return <li><MatchList match={match} key={match} /><li>
    })
    return (
      <div id="tasks">
        <ul>
          {matches}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
   }
});

var MatchList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <a id={this.props.match}>{this.props.match}</a>
    );
  }
});

var matches = [];
document.getElementById("hits-container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if( e.target.classList.contains('matching_link') ) {
    //get matching ID reference
    var $match = e.target.id.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
    matches.push($match);
    //now send to react
    React.render(<MatchApp matches={matches} />, document.getElementById('example'));
  }
});

React.render(<MatchApp matches={matches} />, document.getElementById('example'));
```

Comment: This seems to work great! The only issue I get is if I try to return <MatchList /> like you have. I get " A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object." If i substitute it for text everything works great?

Comment: I'm not sure whats going on then. Did you change something? The codepen with this code works just fine